# How do I create an instance of a subclass from an instance of a superclass?

Tags: python, class, initialization

I made two classes, a parent and a child. What I want to know is if it possible to initialize a child class using the parent class. This is my code:

```
class Pc:

    def __init__(self, brand, processor, price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.processor = processor
        self.price = price

class Laptop(Pc):
    def __init__(self,brand,processor,price, battery):
        Pc.__init__(self,brand,processor,price)
        self.battery = battery
```

Now I can initialize the Laptop class with:

```
b = Laptop('brand','processor','price')
```

But that doesn't seem of much use to me and my teacher hasn't explained it very well. I am interested to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
a = Pc("brand","processor","price")
b = Laptop(a, "battery")
```

When I try this with my code I get an error. Is it even possible to do this ?

Comment: You can define `def __init__(self, pc, battery):` and then copy the `Pc` properties from the `pc` argument.

Comment: the error is that you defined `Laptop.__init__` to receive 4 arguments, and only gave it two.. you need to re-define the function to take the arguments you want to pass it

Comment: you can modify the laptop init with a *argv and work one way or another depending on how many argument you have, or make a classmethod for this particular as an alternative constructor

Comment: It would generally be considered bad design to force you to make two objects when you only want one. You're only making the `Pc` to make the `Laptop` and then you're going to throw it away. The `Pc` doesn't represent anything in itself and it doesn't really make any sense to "turn" a PC into a laptop.

Comment: To me, this seems a (bad) mix of inheritance and composition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
class Laptop(Pc):
    def __init__(self, pc, battery):
        Pc.__init__(self, pc.brand, pc.processor, pc.price)
        self.battery = battery
```

This initializes the inherited properties from the `pc` argument you give to the constructor.

If you want to be able to use the short or long method, you should define the contructor to take keyword arguments, then use an `if` statement to call `Pc.__init__()` appropriately depending on which form was used.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in mechanism in python to achieve what you want, so you have to do it yourself or find a 3rd-party solution.

A good approach to this is that I might take would be to add a class method on the superclass that can clone your object:

```
class Pc:

    @classmethod
    def clone(cls, target, *extra_args, **extra_kwargs):
        return cls(
            target.brand, target.processor, target.price, *extra_args,
            **extra_kwargs)

    def __init__(self, brand, processor, price):
        self.brand = brand
        self.processor = processor
        self.price = price


class Laptop(Pc):

    def __init__(self, brand, processor, price, battery):
        super(Laptop, self).__init__(brand, processor, price)
        self.battery = battery


a = Pc("brand","processor","price")
b = Laptop.clone(a, 'battery')

print(b.battery)
```

But you may find you begin to run into trouble with the initialization arguments. I would recommend keeping required arguments to `__init__()` to a minimum, and then configuring necessary properties afterwards:

```
a = Pc()
a.brand = 'brand'
# etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

there are several option for this

1. if you want to keepthe current behavior, while adding the new one, you can use *arg, for example like

   ```
   class Laptop(Pc):
       def __init__(self, *argv ):
           if len(argv) == 4: #the current one
               brand, processor, price, battery = argv
           elif len(argv) == 2: #the new one
               pc, battery = argv
               brand, processor, price = pc.brand, pc.processor, pc.price
           else:
               raise TypeError
       Pc.__init__(self,brand,processor,price)
       self.battery = battery
   ```

   and use as simple as

   ```
   a = Pc("brand","processor","price")
   b = Laptop(a, "battery")
   ```
2. making a class method to handle this case

   ```
   class Laptop(Pc):

       def __init__(self,brand,processor,price, battery):
           Pc.__init__(self,brand,processor,price)
           self.battery = battery

       @classmethod
       def from_pc_and_battery(cls, pc, battery):
           return cls( pc.brand, pc.processor, pc.price, battery)
   ```

   to use this one, is like this

   ```
   a = Pc("brand","processor","price")
   b = Laptop.from_pc_and_battery(a, "battery")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You do it in somewhat hackish way:

```
import copy
a = Pc("brand","processor","price")
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
b.__class__ = Laptop()
b.battery = battery
```